# excel vba prevent message "with references to unsaved documents" when saving

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink, external

I have an Excel (2016) workbook which the user manually adds values from external links to other workbooks.

When saving the workbook, I am automatically removing the links via an embedded macro in the Workbook_BeforeSave sub and storing only the values.

However, whenever the workbook is saved I am getting the prompt:

Save '{filename.xlsm}' with references to unsaved documents?

This message is redundant as I am removing the physical links when saving.

If at all, how can I suppress this message?

Comment: Or try `Application.DisplayAlerts = False`.

Comment: Which sub would I put that in. I've tried debugging the Workbook_BeforeSave and BeforeClose but both are not triggered before the message is displayed.

Comment: I would put it in the main one, just before you call the embedded macro and then turn it back on after

Comment: The code to remove the links is in the Workbook_BeforeSave sub, as I want it applied only when the user is exiting the workbook. The process is called when the user is selecting the [Save] option from the file menu but I cannot figure out where I can trap the message. The only other solution I can think of is adding a button to the sheet to Save and coding the trap through that. However, that seems a little excessive and non standard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had to resort to having an additional Activex button Visible/Hidden, if any links are identified. I'm checking for the existence of external links in the Worksheet_Change sub and setting the Hidden property of the Activex button accordingly.

I've linked The Activex to a sub, which deletes all links.

This module is also called from the Excel [Save] option and I've setup a call to the new sub in Workbook_BeforeSave.

In most cases the user will reference the Activex button, which means there will be no link when the workbook is saved thus no pop-up message.

Long winded but works.